# Writing mathematical equation for an ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)12

Tags: forecasting, equation, arima, sas-studio

I would like to understand how to write the equation of an ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)12. I'm using SAS Studio to estimate the parameters and here is the result
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHoSO.png)

I've tried to substitutes the the estimated parameters to the general seasonal ARIMA model ([The general seasonal ARIMA model][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY9NW.png
And here is the result [ARIMA(0,1,1)(1,0,0)12][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oGkZ.png

I do not know if it is correct or wrong and I need the equation to be Zt = ....

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AmmarAbdullah : Here is the results that I have tried https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oGkZ.png